# ngx_http_limit_req module can not limit request correct

Tags: nginx

I want to protect my nginx server under a safe concurrency request, so I had set the nginx server(nginx 1.6.2) limitted on 30000 qps by config like this:

```
limit_req_zone $server_port zone=perport:10m rate=30000r/s;
limit_req_status 597;
limit_req zone=perport burst=0 nodelay;
```

But the nginx server have just 6000 qps, I had got many limitted error.

I had tried to read the source code for the reason, and the I found this ([source link](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/release-1.6.2/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.c#L379-L420)):

```
379: tp = ngx_timeofday();
380: now = (ngx_msec_t) (tp->sec * 1000 + tp->msec);
...
409: ms = (ngx_msec_int_t) (now - lr->last);
410:
411: excess = lr->excess - ctx->rate * ngx_abs(ms) / 1000 + 1000;
...
419: if ((ngx_uint_t) excess > limit->burst) {
420:     return NGX_BUSY;
...
```

I think there has a bug:

1. When the `ngx_abs(ms)` got 0, the `rate` value can not affect `excess` whatever it set to be.
2. When two request had same hash key and arrive at same time (same millisecond).
3. The `excess` will be `1000`
4. The request would be `NGX_BUSY` when no `burst` set.

Cause I used the `server_port` as the hash key, or whatever other key which would take concurrency request，whatever I set the rate to `30000r/s`,`3000000r/s` or `3000000000r/s`, it make no sence.

I read the latest [nginx(1.11.6) code](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/release-1.11.6/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.c#L371-L411), looks like no changes.

Comment: It's hard to read a question here. Maybe you want to go via the [offical channel](http://nginx.org/en/support.html). Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Your issue seems to be about server configuration. If you realy have a specific question, [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) imho would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Nginx implements [Leaky bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) and this is exactly how it works without `burst`